# Selecting element having two classes and wrapping them

Tags: jquery

**HTML**

```
<div>
 <span class="openParen bm0">(</span>
 <span class="closeParen bm0">)</span>
 <span class="openParen bm3">(</span>
 <span class="openCurly bm1">{</span>
 <span class="openParen bm2">(</span>
 <span class="closeParen bm2">)</span>
 <span class="closeParen bm3">)</span> 
 <span class="closeCurly bm1">}</span>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
I wanted this to be wrapped in `<span class="new"></span>` by pairs using the bm classname, and i only wanted to wrapped those with Paren on their class name

**NOT WRAPPING PROPERLY**

```
<div>
  <div>if<span class="openParen bm1">(</span>b<3 && b>0<span class="closeParen bm1">)</span>{</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with confirming it? i cant work it out, i thought i done it wrong, so now i'll check my code to debug. Thanks for the very constructive comment

Comment: I think a comment that explains how you could have solved your problems by yourself is more constructive than a prepared answer. Finding what you need in google is probably one of the most important capabilities a programmer can have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) and use the `bm0` class to select the elements

```
var ops = /(==|<=|>=|!=|>|<)/,
    prev = /(if|else\s+if|while|for)/;
$('.openParen').each(function () {
    var bm = this.className.match(/\b(bm\d+)\b/)[1],
        $this = $(this),
        $close = $('.closeParen.' + bm);

    var $set = $(this),
        next = this.nextSibling;
    while (next) {
        $set = $set.add(next);
        if ($close.is(next)) {
            break;
        }
        next = next.nextSibling;
    }

    if (ops.test($set.text())) {
        var prevEl = this.previousSibling;
        var $span = $set.wrapAll('<span class="new"></span>').parent();
        if (prevEl && prevEl.nodeType == 3 && prev.test($(prevEl).text())) {
            $span.prepend(prevEl)
        }
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j9fyC/)

Comment: @fireflieslive please try to recreate the issue in the fiddle

Comment: @ArunPJohny: just please help me with this, ill give this question a bounty. I badly need this

Comment: @fireflieslive what is the problem here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36721/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-fireflieslive)

Comment: @ArunPJohny: one more help, i must not wrap ( ) w/out a conditional operator like ==, <=, >=, !=, >, <. more than 50+ bounty mark my word. really need this ^^

Comment: @fireflieslive Can you provide a example of when it should and should not wrap

Comment: @arunPJohnny help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18809745/wrapping-conditional-blocks-in-a-contenteditable-div-using-regex

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code should do the trick :

```
$.each($('.openParen'), function(index, startParen){
    var classes = $(startParen).attr('class').split(' ');
    var bmClass = $.grep(classes, function(thisElement, index){
        return thisElement.toString().match("^bm");
    });
    $(startParen).nextUntil($('.' + bmClass[0])).andSelf().add($('.' + bmClass[0] +     ':last')).wrapAll('<span class="new"></span>');
});
```

Explanation :

1. Select all elements with class "openParen".
2. Loop through this list and get each associated ".bm" class.

   ```
   var bmClass = $.grep(classes, function(thisElement, index){
           return thisElement.toString().match("^bm");
       });
   ```
3. This code gets the class name starting with keyword "bm".
4. Now starting with the current element select all elements until next element with needed "bm" class.

   ```
   $(startParen).nextUntil($('.' + bmClass[0]))
   ```
5. Add current and final "bm" elements as jquery nextUntil() will not add them to the wrapped set.

   ```
   $(startParen).nextUntil($('.' + bmClass[0])).andSelf().add($('.' + bmClass[0] + ':last'))
   ```
6. Wrap the set with  tag.

   ```
   $(startParen).nextUntil($('.' + bmClass[0])).andSelf().add($('.' + bmClass[0] + ':last')).wrapAll('<span class="new"></span>');
   ```
7. And that's it. You now have your spans with "paren" keyword nicely wrapped in outer spans with class "new". Also grouped according to their corresponding "bm" classes.
8. Now all we need to do is just include this code in dom load event and we are done.